# send authentication request from one rails application to other rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi i am new in rails .I have two rails application suppose A & B when user wants to login  in application A ,its username & password send it towards application B ,B authenticate it and send back responce to the application A,and then user able to login in  system A.
BOth applicaton uses different databases.Please if any sample example is there suggest me or what code is to write for that or what i use to do this.

Comment: And the problem is? Are you using the same database? Are application B only for authentication? A bit more info please.

Comment: and are they under 2 different domains, because Rails cookie session or remember_me cookie rely on the domain name for the cookie to be sent to the web server

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the other DB from a model and check against the users table.  Here is an example:

```
a_development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: a_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

b_development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: b_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

# In app B: 

class AppAUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "a_#{RAILS_ENV}"
end

AppAUser.find(params[:user_name], params[:password])
```